# Can people with an ISP access your network if it is on the Default Free Zone?

Tags: routing, bgp, networking

Let's say you have a router on the DFZ (despite costing an absurd ammount of money). Would your network work the same as if you have an ISP in terms of web hosting, etc?

Can people still access your network?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I've just started learning about the DFZ/BGP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course.  You would still be advertising your network, and everyone would be able to reach it.

Carriers on the edge of the DFZ may advertise a default route to their customers.  The source for that route would be the DFZ edge router, which has your prefix in its BGP table.

The DFZ is just a group of BGP peers where all routes are explicit -- no one is advertising a default route because there is no path for "everything else." All prefixes (with appropriate summarization) are announced into the zone.